# Show stock of configurable products on Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I'm new on Magento and I have problems to show stock of configurable product. I have tried a lot of things that I found on Google, Stackoverflow, Magento Forums, but I failed. Here is the only solution that I cannot try:

> $_product is your configurable product.
>
> To get all its simple use :
>
> $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product);
>
> So you might have something like :
>
> foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null,
>   $_product) as $simple) {
>        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
>        echo $simple->getName()." with size ".$simple->getSize()." have a stock of $stock";
>        echo '
> ';  } I let you adapt to your precise needs and ask question if needed

My problem is: I don't know where I can apply this solution!

[image: ScreenShot]()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform two step to get this working however I have checked this with version 1.8 but hope it will work in your case also

step 1. copy file app/code/core/mage/catalog/block/product/view/type/configurable.php

And create a folder under app/code/local with same directory structure mage/catalog/block/product/view/type/configurable.php

Now find function name getJsonConfig in configuration.php file.

Go to following code

```html
   $info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                        'label'     => $value['label'],
                        'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                        'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'  => $productsIndex,
  
                    );
```

Before this code place below two lines of code

```html
$simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productsIndex); 
$qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty();
```

Here you can see that i'm getting product stock by product id, now in info option array code you have to add one parameter

```html
$info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                        'label'     => $value['label'],
                        'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                        'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'  => $productsIndex,
   'qty'       => $qty, // we are sending stock parameter so we can use it latter in drop down field
  
                    );
```

step 2. Now go js/varian/configuration.js

find the following line

```html
 if(allowedProducts.size()>0){
                    options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                    element.options[index] = new Option(this.getOptionLabel(options[i], options[i].price), options[i].id);
```

Place following line under this

```html
element.options[index].innerHTML += " Stock is :"+options[i].qty;
```

that's it all about cheer

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Hey guy!!! It works!!! I'm facing a little problem, the first item of this select shows "null". Example:

21 - Stock: null
22 - Stock: 2
23 - Stock: 4

I'm using CE 1.9 version of Magento. How can I solve this issue? Thanks, @sagar

Answer (score 0):

with app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
$simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productsIndex); 
$qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty();

                    $info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                        'label'     => $value['label'],
                        'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                        'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'  => $productsIndex,
                        'qty'       => $qty, // we are sending stock parameter so we can use it latter in drop down field
                    );
                    $optionPrices[] = $configurablePrice;
                }
            }
```

and at js/varien/configurable.js

```
if(allowedProducts.size()>0){
                    options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                    element.options[index] = new Option(this.getOptionLabel(options[i], options[i].price), options[i].id);
                    if (typeof options[i].price != 'undefined') {
                        element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].price);
                    }
                    element.options[index].innerHTML += " Stock is :"+options[i].qty; 
                    element.options[index].config = options[i];
                    index++;
                }
```

isn't working at 1.9.4... is it something wrong?