# Show Stock of Configurable Products - Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319680/show-stock-of-configurable-products-on-magento-1-9) to show the stock of my configurable products, but I'm getting an error:

[error-magento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfKLz.jpg)

The only problem only occurs with the first item, where it shows "null".

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Configurable.php

```
$simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productsIndex); 
$qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty();

$info['options'][] = array(
                    'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                    'label'     => $value['label'],
                    'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                    'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                    'products'  => $productsIndex,
        'qty'       => $qty, // we are sending stock parameter so we can use it latter in drop down field

                );
```

Comment: You should include the code you're using directly in the question itself.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yikes! That is a lot of code. You might want to refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve